# Facebook API won't load Phots

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, sdk

I have been trying to get Facebook API to load my photos. I just keep getting array[0].

I am very new to Facebook Developer, so any help would be great.

Thanks

My code:

```
if(response.status == "connected"){
        FB.api("/me/", function(resp2){
            console.log(resp2);
            $("#userinfo").append("<br/>Welcome "+resp2.name+"!");
            // store info in object
            userinfo.name = resp2.name;
            //userinfo.gender = resp2.name;
            //userinfo.id = resp2.id;
            //alert(resp2.id)
        });
        FB.api("/me/picture", function(pic_resp){
            console.log(pic_resp);
            $("#userinfo").append("<img src='"+pic_resp.data.url+"' />");
            // store info in object
            userinfo.pic = pic_resp.data.url;
        });
            FB.api("/me/photos", function(photos_resp){
            console.log(photos_resp);

        });
    } else{
      FB.login(function(response){
      },{scope: 'user_photos'});
    }
```

Comment: that code is weird. why are you using FB.login when the user is already connected?

Comment: Only if the user is not connected will FB.login run. I have also tried "else if(response.status === 'not_authorized')". It still will not work.

Comment: not according to your coce: if(response.status == "connected"){
FB.login...

Comment: also, i assume the whole thing is in a callback function? because that´s a very bad idea, you should never call FB.login in a callback function. make sure you understand what "asynchronous" means.

Comment: this may help you: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: Thank you. Given me something to think about/try. The whole thing is actually part of an object and, you're right, their is a callback function.

Comment: Thank you, Luschn. I removed the callback function and implemented the ideas on the link you provided. While my code seems improved, I am still getting array[0] for Photos.

Comment: are you trying with an app developer or any other user? are you 100% sure you get asked for user_photos in the auth process?

Comment: I just deleted the app, and created a new one. During the authentication process I am not asked to give permission for my photos. ...Really, I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Note: All the basic permissions work fine

Comment: again: are you trying with an app developer or any other user?

Comment: check out my answer. i am 99% sure it´s the reason why it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `user_photos` does not work in the authorization process, you are most likely trying with a user that is not an App Admin/Developer/Tester. Before you can make that permission work for any other user, you have to go through a review process: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

If that is not the case, if you still don´t get asked for the permission, there´s something wrong with your login process.

Comment: Thank you, Luschn. I am using the app as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [FB API Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/photos#read) there's an "error" property in the response. Please check that out.

Quote:

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/me/photos",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: well, he does have a console.log in the callback, so he actually should get any error already.

Comment: Oh, still early. My bad.

Comment: Since I can't comment to your original post; Have you tried calling /me/photos first? I'm not an FB API user but it assume it's worth the try.

Comment: Thank you. I just gave that a try with the same result.